# OpenCV DNN Face detector

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, blob

def detect_video(image):

```
gray=image


blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(gray, 1.0, (300, 300), [104, 117, 123], False, False)
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()
bboxes = []
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
frameWidth=image.shape[1]
frameHeight=image.shape[0]
for i in range(detections.shape[2]):
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
    if confidence > 0.7:
        x1 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 3] * frameWidth)
        y1 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 4] * frameHeight)
        x2 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 5] * frameWidth)
        y2 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 6] * frameHeight)
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,0),3)
        try:
            image1 = gray[y1:(y2), x1:(x2)]

            img = cv2.resize(image1, (48,48), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC) / 255.

            prediction=model1.predict_proba(img.reshape(1,48,48,1))

            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            cv2.putText(image,str(emotions[prediction[0].argmax()]),(x1,y1+10), font, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

            result=prediction
            if result is not None:
                if result[0][6] < 0.6:
                    result[0][6] = result[0][6] - 0.12
                    result[0][:3] += 0.01
                    result[0][4:5] += 0.04
    # write the different emotions and have a bar to indicate probabilities for each class
                for index, emot in enumerate(emotion):
                    cv2.putText(image, emot, (10, index * 20 + 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 1)
                    cv2.rectangle(image, (130, index * 20 + 10), (130 + int(result[0][index] * 100), (index + 1) * 20 + 4), (255, 0, 0), -1)
                emt=[prediction[0][0],prediction[0][1],prediction[0][2],prediction[0][3],prediction[0][4],prediction[0][5],prediction[0][6]]
                indx=np.arange(len(emotion))
                plt.bar(indx,emt,color='blue')

                plt.xticks(indx,emotion)
                plt.savefig("ab.png")
                cv2.imshow("graph",cv2.imread("ab.png"))
                plt.clf()
                #cv2.waitKey(5)
                #plt.show()
                #return indx,emt


        except:
            #print("----->Problem during resize .Probably Cant detect any face")
            continue
return image
```

I have made my own model and trained on KDEF dataset.Now when I am giving the video as an input , it detects the face in the video but it makes two bounding boxes.Can anyone help me whats the mistake in the code.Its running successfully but just creating two bounding boxes.The input which the neural networks accepts is 48*48.

Answer (score 0):

first select the detection which has the most significant confidence then draw it on image.

```
detection_index = 0
max_confidence = 0

for i in range(detections.shape[2]):
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
    if max_confidence < confidence:
        max_confidence = confidence
        detection_index = i

i = detection_index

x1 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 3] * frameWidth)
y1 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 4] * frameHeight)
x2 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 5] * frameWidth)
y2 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 6] * frameHeight)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 0), 3)
try:
    image1 = gray[y1:(y2), x1:(x2)]

img = cv2.resize(image1, (48, 48), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC) / 255.

prediction = model1.predict_proba(img.reshape(1, 48, 48, 1))

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(image, str(emotions[prediction[0].argmax()]), (x1, y1 + 10), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

result = prediction
if result is not None:
    if result[0][6] < 0.6:
        result[0][6] = result[0][6] - 0.12
        result[0][:3] += 0.01
        result[0][4:5] += 0.04
        # write the different emotions and have a bar to indicate probabilities for each class
    for index, emot in enumerate(emotion):
        cv2.putText(image, emot, (10, index * 20 + 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (130, index * 20 + 10), (130 + int(result[0][index] * 100), (index + 1) * 20 + 4),
                      (255, 0, 0), -1)
    emt = [prediction[0][0], prediction[0][1], prediction[0][2], prediction[0][3], prediction[0][4],
           prediction[0][5], prediction[0][6]]
    indx = np.arange(len(emotion))
    plt.bar(indx, emt, color='blue')

    plt.xticks(indx, emotion)
    plt.savefig("ab.png")
    cv2.imshow("graph", cv2.imread("ab.png"))
    plt.clf()
    # cv2.waitKey(5)
    # plt.show()
    # return indx,emt


except:
    # print("----->Problem during resize .Probably Cant detect any face")
    continue
return image
```